# How to pass an environment variable into a RUN command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
version : '2'
services :
    s1 :
        build : .
        environment :
            HELLO : world
```

And a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN /bin/bash -c 'echo "$HELLO" > /txt'
```

How can I end up with an image with a `txt` file holding the text `world` in it?

Right now when I test the given example, the file is empty!

**[UPDATE]**

If I put the environment variable in the `Dockerfile` **it works just fine**, Which makes me think it's a `docker-compose` issue!

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV HELLO=world
RUN /bin/bash -c 'echo "$HELLO" > /txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environments defined in the docker-compose.yml will not be accessible at build time.

To achieve that, you will have to use the `args` option of the `build` field (only supported in version 2 file format of docker-compose). It will let you add build arguments.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args

Find below how to use it:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services :
    s1 :
        build :
            context: .
            args:
                HELLO: world
```

Also, note that you will have to define in your **Dockerfile** an `ARG` tag with the same key name.

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG HELLO
RUN echo "$HELLO" > /txt
```